# Trying to accomplish imagemagick.js functionality in javascript; How to use Processing.js to identify and convert image?

Tags: javascript, image, process, imagemagick, processing.js

I'm having a problem with Chrome where it prints grayscale images from my website with a red overlay. This is a known bug with Chrome that is supposedly being fixed, but until it is I need to find a way to make my images print correctly. I found this hack in a thread about the issue that mentions imagemagick:

> I found that this was happening to grayscale jpgs. Using imagemagick I was able to mass-reprocess     images to avoid this issue using the following commands.
>
> if `identify -format "%r" file.jpg` returns "PsuedoClass Gray" or "PsuedoClassGray"
>   then run the following: `convert file.jpg -type Truecolor file.jpg`

However, I imagemagick.js doesn't work; I tried using it and got an error "require is not defined", and discovered that I cannot use node.js script in my browser. Apparently Processing.js is supposed to be a decent javascript library to mimic imagemagick, but I can't figure out how to do the same things. This is what I was trying to do with imagemagick:

```
im.identify(['-format', '%wx%h', '@Model.DatabaseName' + '.jpg'], function(err, output) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // if output returns PsuedoClass Gray, do im.convert
});
```

How can I do this with Processing.js, or is there another library that I should use to do this?

Comment: You mentioned "cannot use node.js in my browser". Did you mean your server? Where are you trying to run `convert` ?  I viewed your http://oceanstatejoblot.com/_images/coupon/104106_BW.jpg image and it looked fine in my Chrome version 39.0.2171.95m.  `identify` reports it as PseudoClassGray.

Comment: If you try to print that image it prints in red

Answer (score 0):

Your best workaround is to change the code on the server which converts your original color jpeg into B&W. If you are already using ImageMagick `convert` for that job, a few more command-line arguments will give you a Truecolor file containing the B&W image. You don't need to do it as a second `convert`.

For a browser-based solution, processing.js is overkill. This works for me:

```
<!doctype html>
<html><head></head><body>
<img src="http://www.oceanstatejoblot.com/_images/coupon/049683_Final.jpg"> Final.jpg<br><br>
<img id="bw1" src="http://www.oceanstatejoblot.com/_images/coupon/049683_BW.jpg"> BW.jpg<br><br>
<canvas id="bw2" width="352" height="245"></canvas> Canvas<br>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("bw2").getContext("2d").drawImage(document.getElementById("bw1"), 0, 0);
};
</script>
</body></html>
```

Chrome Print Preview:

[image]